# Java Web Serive NTLM Authentication

Tags: java, ntlm

I need to call asp.net Web Service in Java Client Class and I am using NTLM authentication. But I am getting exception "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

```
 NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator( "username", "password" );
            Authenticator.setDefault( authenticator );
```

I have created NtlmAuthenticator. java class.

```
public class NtlmAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{

    private String user;
    private String password;

    public NtlmAuthenticator ( String user, String password )
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        PasswordAuthentication auth = new PasswordAuthentication( user, password.toCharArray() );
        return auth;
    }
}
```

But When I try to access web service through **Soap UI** Software I am able to get response.

Please Help on this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't you need a domain for NTLM?

Comment: I know domain. I added domain to username like domian\\username